# Redimensionar uma imagem em um elemento canvas com js

Tags: javascript, canvas, redimensionamento

## Problema

Redimensionamento de imagem com *JavaScript*

## Possível solução

Utilizar o elemento *canvas* para redesenhar a imagem, redimensioná-la e depois renderizar a imagem novamente.

Abaixo serão citados **2 casos de uso** meramente ilustrativos, pois os tamanhos das imagens não serão fixos como esses, sendo utilizados somente para ilustrar a orientação (retrato/paisagem) da imagem.

## Caso 1

Este caso utiliza a *Div* de dimensões 851x315

### Div:

[image: Div 851x315]

### Caso 1.1:

Redimensionar uma imagem de dimensões **1080x1920** para apresentação nesta *div*.

### Imagem:

[image: Imagem 1080x1920]

### Caso 1.2:

Redimensionar uma imagem de dimensões **1920x1080** para apresentação nesta *div*.

### Imagem:

[image: Imagem 1920x1080]

## Caso 2

Este caso utiliza a *Div* de dimensões 500x450

### Div:

[image: Div 500x450]

### Caso 2.1:

Redimensionar uma imagem de dimensões **1080x1920** para apresentação nesta *div*.

### Imagem:

[image: Imagem 1080x1920]

### Caso 2.2:

Redimensionar uma imagem de dimensões **1920x1080** para apresentação nesta *div*.

### Imagem:

[image: Imagem 1920x1080]

## Lógica utilizada:

O redimensionamento não deve ser feito com intuito de modelar a imagem para caber na *div*, mas sim mantendo a proporcionalidade de suas dimensões, até que uma destas se iguale à uma das dimensões da *div*.

O bloco de código abaixo é auto explicativo:

```
if (alturaImagem <= larguraImagem) {
    proporcao = alturaDiv / alturaImagem;
    novaLarguraImagem = larguraImagem * proporcao;
    novaAlturaImagem = alturaDiv;
} else {
    proporcao = larguraDiv / larguraImagem;
    novaLarguraImagem = larguraDiv;
    novaAlturaImagem = alturaImagem * proporcao;
}
```

O problema de utilizar este código e um elemento *canvas* para redimensionar a imagem é que, logo após o processo, há uma queda grande da qualidade da imagem, dependendo da sua resolução.

Se for uma imagem de dimensões próximas à da *div*, quase não haverá queda na qualidade da mesma, mas se a diferença for muito grande (exemplo: redimensionar uma imagem de dimensões 7680x4320 para uma *div* de dimensões 851x315) a qualidade da imagem cai demais e isso fica bem aparente.

Após fazer várias pesquisas sobre isto, encontrei um *post* no *SOen*, [que ensina a fazer o redimensionamento, utilizando um método chamado **step-down**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861447/html5-canvas-drawimage-how-to-apply-antialiasing), que ao meu entender significa *redução passo-a-passo* (me corrijam se não for isso), há uma fórmula pra calcular o número de passos que será usado, como explicado no *post* linkado.

### Meu código:

```
var file, img, width, height, ratio, nWidth, nHeight;
var _URL = (window.URL) ? window.URL : window.webkitURL;

if ((file = e.target.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    img.onload = function () {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height;

        // Criação do primeiro elemento canvas

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Altura e largura da div

        tWidth = $("div#mp-change-bg").width();
        tHeight = $("div#mp-change-bg").height();

        // Criação do segundo elemento canvas, que será manipulado off-screen

        var oc = document.createElement("canvas");
        var octx = oc.getContext("2d");

        oc.width = width * 0.5;
        oc.height = height * 0.5;

        // 1º passo

        octx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

        // 2º passo

        octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5);

        // Definição das novas dimensões da imagem

        if (height <= width) {
            ratio = tHeight / height;
            canvas.width = width * ratio;
            canvas.height = tHeight;
        } else {
            ratio = tWidth / width;
            canvas.width = tWidth;
            canvas.height = height * ratio;
        }

        // 3º e último passo

        ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        $("img#mp-image-bg").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL("image/png")).css("display", "block");
    };
}
```

Fiz o código praticamente baseado na resposta que foi dada no *post* do *SOen*, e este é funcional para o **Caso 2** citado no início do post.

A imagem abaixo é a original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, a mesma imagem aplicada à *div*:

[image: Onça na div]

Como podem ver, estou utilizando um [plugin para reposicionar a imagem na *div*, com *drag and drop*](https://github.com/tybro0103/jWindowCrop). Independente da orientação da imagem usada, ela é redimensionada corretamente, com exceção do **Caso 1**, também citado no início do *post*.

Utilizando a mesma imagem da onça, olhem o resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem ao invés de redimensionada, foi esticada totalmente. O problema pode ter a ver com o número de passos à utilizar, até porque através do cálculo, **o resultado encontrado é 0**, ou seja, não é pra utilizar passo nenhum, mas mesmo omitindo os passos e redimensionando direto, o resultado é o mesmo.

Peço desculpas se o *post* ficou muito extenso, mas tentei ser o mais claro possível expondo meu problema.

Qualquer dúvida, ou se faltou algo, peçam nos comentários. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considerei para a resposta que a imagem deve preencher todo o espaço.

O código apresentado verifica somente a proporção da imagem original. Modifiquei o código para verificar as proporções da imagem e da `<div>` e recalcular as posições de "corte" de `.drawImage()`.

O exemplo abaixo coloca a imagem em elementos `<div>` de diversos tamanhos.

```js
(function(){
  var image = new Image();
  image.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
    // tamanho original
    , oWidth = this.width
    , oHeight = this.height;
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      ,   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      // coordenadas origem (source)
      ,   sx = 0
      ,   sy = 0
      ,   sWidth = oWidth
      ,   sHeight = oHeight
      // tamanho destino
      ,   dWidth = divs[i].offsetWidth
      ,   dHeight = divs[i].offsetHeight
      // tamanho ideal
      ,   iWidth = Math.round(sHeight / dHeight * dWidth)
      ,   iHeight = Math.round(sWidth / dWidth * dHeight);
      if (sWidth > iWidth) { // cortar na largura
        sx = parseInt((sWidth - iWidth) / 2);
        sWidth = iWidth;
      } else if (sHeight > iHeight) { // cortar na altura
        sy = parseInt((sHeight - iHeight) / 2);
        sHeight = iHeight;
      }
      canvas.width = dWidth;
      canvas.height = dHeight;
      ctx.drawImage(this, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, 0, 0, dWidth, dHeight);
      divs[i].appendChild(canvas);
    }
  }, false);
  image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY8Iy.png';
})();
```

```css
div {
 margin: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div style="width: 315px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente para mim! Obrigado!